# eNom .com domain in reactivation period, expires in 2012

Tags: domains

There is a .com domain which I want to backorder (with eNoms NameJet). It's whois has been cleared to 'Reactivation Period'. Registrar is eNom.

Reactivation Period means that the domain is expired/deleted and will shortly be released to the registry or eNoms domain bidding system, right?
The problem is that whois states a expiration date of Aug 2012. What does that mean? Will the domain be in reactivation period until Aug 2012? (It's December 2011 now.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Enom Registration Agreement:

> a. Reactivation Period Process. For a period of approximately 30 days after expiration of the term of domain name registration services, we may provide a procedure by which expired domain name registration services may be renewed. We may, but are not obligated to, offer this process, called the "reactivation period." You assume all risks and all consequences if you wait until close to or after the expiration of the original term of domain name registration services to attempt to renew the domain name registration services. We may, in our sole discretion, choose not to offer a reactivation period and we shall not be liable therefore. The reactivation period renewal process, if any, may involve additional fees which we and your Primary Service Provider may determine. We may make expired domain name services(s) available to third parties, we may auction off the rights to expired domain name services (the auction beginning close to the end or after the end of the reactivation period), and/or expired domain name registration services may be re-registered to any party at any time.

Given that the WHOIS information says the domain name expires in August 2012 would mean that you'll be waiting until September 2012 to have the possibility of bidding on this domain name (expiration + 30 days). That's also assuming that whomever has this domain already does not renew their registration within that 30 day period after expiration. If they decide to renew their registration it will reset the waiting period to the new expiration date plus the 30 day reactivation process.

Comment: The expiry date was Aug 2011 and _then_ it came into `Reactivion Period`. Now idea why eNom renewed it for another year, I'm quite sure the owner didn't. That's the odd part about it. According to the quote it shouldn't be in `Reactivion Period` for a whole year. Thanks anyway!